# Which mold species are these?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, home-biology

A friend of mine in Los Angeles recently put a petri dish with some mold-friendly substrate under a vent for two days, and a whole rainbow of mold species grew on it.

[image]

What are the different mold species present on this dish? Are any of them dangerous to human health?

Comment: you need to give a lot more information and if possible take pictures with 50x magnification of each type in your sample.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP can give "a lot more information" except maybe what the "mold-friendly substrate" was, but I think an answer linking to a resource for common household mold species would be a wonderful and helpful answer. +1 for home experiments!

Comment: @trondhansen - I am happy to give any other information that I have and that might be relevant, if you tell me what you are looking for. I did not take the picture, and my friend does not have a microscope, so I cannot easily get you 50-times-higher-resolution pictures. I imagine some "best-guess" answer might have to do if there are various mold species with similar phenotypes.

Comment: The wet pink ones are likely to be either a yeast or something like *Serratia marcescens*. We would need microscope pictures of stained samples from the others to attempt ID. Filamentous fungus is about as close as you can get otherwise. Huge range to choose from...